# Testing values of array objects

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

If i have an array like:

```
[
{ "user": "tom",
  "email": "ee@co.com"
},
{ "user": "james",
  "email": "bb@co.com"
},
{ "user": "ryan",
  "email": "rr@co.com"
}
]
```

But it's not always being returned in that order - how can i check if `ryan`, for example, exists somewhere in one of these objects?

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) (or want to) then I would use its [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find):

```
_.find(array, { user: "ryan" })
```

Or with a few more characters you can do it without lodash:

```
array.find(elem => elem.user === "ryan")
```

Both return `undefined` if a matching element is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Function return true if array contains `ryan`.

```
var input = [
{ "user": "tom",
  "email": "ee@co.com"
},
{ "user": "james",
  "email": "bb@co.com"
},
{ "user": "ryan",
  "email": "rr@co.com"
}
]
var output = input.some(function(eachRow){
    return eachRow.user === 'ryan';
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

My method to solve that is to extract the targeted fields into arrays then check the value.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('unit test', function() {
  it('runs test', function() {
    const users = [
      { "user": "tom",
        "email": "ee@co.com"
      },
      { "user": "james",
        "email": "bb@co.com"
      },
      { "user": "ryan",
        "email": "ryan@co.com"
      }
    ];
    const names = extractField(users, 'user'); // ['tom', 'james', 'ryan']   

    expect(names).to.include('ryan');
  });

  function extractField(users, fieldName) {
    return users.map(user => user[fieldName]);
  }
});
```

I'm using [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) for assertion. In case you want to check in other fields, we just use the extract methods.

```
const emails = extractField(users, 'email');
expect(emails).to.include('ryan');
```

Hope it helps